# Strange router behaviour after upgrading to Angular 8

Tags: angular, angular8

So, I have this hybrid app, i.e. some less used modules are in angularJs but most of the app is in Angular 7. Recently I decided to update it to Angular 8... and the thing is, that although code builds just fine in the run-time I am experiencing really strange behaviour, e.g. no matter what route I click, no matter from which route I click that route, right after navigation to the desired route ends the app triggers another navigation and it gets back to the point where I started. This unwanted redirection has a "popstate" trigger. Of course there where no similar issues on Angular 7. I pretty much have no idea what's going on as the app doesn't throw any errors.

I have routes configured according to the Angular 8 lazy loading notation, i.e.: `{ path: 'my-module', loadChildren: () => import('./my-module/my-module.module').then(m => m.MyModule) }` (I had to change those manually, as I am using custom webpack build, so I don't have easy access to angular-cli tools, but those should be fine). I am also using hash in my routing strategy.

Sorry that I am unable to provide you with minimal reproducible example, but I can't give you entire app, and If I was able to recreate it "artificially", in this case, I would probably find the right answer on my own :/.

If anyone has any idea what should I check I'd really appreciate that.

Comment: If it's ideas you're looking for, check 1) your routing modules 2) your guards (all of them, not just canActivate) 3) any component importing a router dependency 4) any component having a `routerLink` in its template

Comment: After you bootstrap your AngularJS app, do you call `setUpLocationSync`? I had this, and was getting weird routing issues in my upgrade app, and I had to implement a custom `setUpLocationSync` handler that skipped the location sync.